# How to make Othello chess pieces with only Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, chess

I am thinking of using a short cylinder as the shape of the chess piece, but then I can't figure out how to make one side of it to be black and the other side to be white.

I want to do it this way as I want to have the pieces flipped during the game, just like we play Othello in the real world.

Edit:
In addition to Nigel's suggestion, a "thin" sphere with a "black/white" texture applied to it can also get the job done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 cylinders ("black" and "white") properly ("black" is standing on "white" head) grouped under one parent object. Then:

1. In "black" cylinder's script set cylinder color to black: `this.renderer.material.color = Color.black;`
2. In "white" cylinder's script ... Yep, set color to white.

Comment: thanks, i was too ignorant that i didnt think of combining 2 cylinders together as one :)